# BinaryTree functions - complexity

Tags: binary-tree

I am just writing down different function, which are operation what can be done on a binary tree.

I am wondering what is the running time of this function, trying to get rid with them:

```
  getMaxDepth(Tree) //What can be the time complexity here? 
    if Tree.root = NIL return 0 // BaseCase
    leftDepth := 1 + getMaxDepth(Tree.root.left)
    rightDepth := 1 + getMaxDepth(Tree.root.right)
    if leftDepth > rightDepth then return leftDepth;
    else return rightDepth;


  internalNodeCount(Node n) // And here?
    if isLeaf(n) then return 0
    return 1 + internalNodeCount(n.left) + internalNodeCount(n.right)

  isLeaf(Node n)
    return n=NIL OR (n.left=NIL AND n.right=nil);
```

`GetMaxDepth` I assume the time complexity is O(n) because I need to traverse the whole tree recursively for ever node....what can be a good explanation?

InternalNodeCount I guess it is the same complexity O(n) for the same reason.....

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood it looks like you are looking for some proof.

For getMaxDepth here is the explanation:

```
T(1) = c1
T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k-1) + c2
where
T(n) = Time to process tree of n nodes 
n = number of nodes
k = nodes in left subtree
n-k-1 = nodes in right subtree
c1, c2 = constants (not dependent upon n) 
(Time to calculate the depth of the tree from given left and right subtree depth)
```

The same could be applied to internalNode too excepts the contants would be different.